# grunt-serve doesn't serve index.html with '/' request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I have a problem getting a local server with grunt-serve task to behave like a normal server should. My `grunt.initConfig` object is like follows:

```
  grunt.initConfig({
    'serve': {
      'path': '/Users/honkdonky/Desktop/testspace/angular',
      },
      'options': {
        'port': '9999'
      }
    }
  });
```

but when I request this link:

http://localhost:9999/

index.html there is not rendered. Instead what I see is a list of available files. The project should route requests to '/' by rendering index.html and routing as configured in angularjs module. Configuration of which is as follows:

```
phoneApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/phones', {
                templateUrl: 'phone-list.html',
                controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
            }).
            when('/phones/:phoneId', {
                templateUrl: 'phone-detail.html',
                controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/phones'
            });
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [grunt-serve](https://github.com/lud2k/grunt-serve) package is used to **run tasks** and **serve files**, it can't render / to index.html, if you need a web server, you can use [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could help. But I suggest you could try using [gulp-webserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webserver). It's pretty much easier to use and have a cool features such as livereload (automatically refresh the browser whenever there's any changes in the folder).

Comment: Adding gulp to the list of tools is not a good option, but your main idea is right; grunt-serve is just not the best option as a server.